# Nested Table automate CSS width issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested

I've searched through the net and can not figure this out.

I have a nested table and would like to set the width of the first td to be automated so that the first table width is the same as the second table.  I'll try to explain in the code below.

Full html code is here (http://pastebin.com/KEMPJscU) where the automate width is empty (`<td style="">`). I would like to set that width to be automated.

The reason that I would like to do this is that the table 2 width is set by a script (that I have no control over).

Comment: In your example, you have two nested tables, each in one of two `td`'s forming the row of the parent/container table.  Table 2 (left one) will have a width set by a width and you want Table 1 (right one) to take on the same width as Table 2.  The parent table will then have a width twice as wide as Table 2 (approximately true taking into account padding, borders and margins).  Is this right?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to add the CSS style "width: 100%" to your first inner table?